# Authentication Code doesnt update on logout

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

I am using:
SpringBoot 3.2.1
springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.3.0
spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:3.2.1
Its a maven project build with openjdk21.

Case:
I am trying to add Authentication in Swagger-UI, so if i want to test the api, i need an access-token. I am currently doing this to authenticate through openID Connect:

```
@SecurityScheme(
        name = "keycloak",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.OAUTH2,
        flows = @OAuthFlows(
                authorizationCode = @OAuthFlow(
                        tokenUrl = "<tokenurl>",
                        authorizationUrl = "<authorizationurl>"
                )
        )
)
```

So now a Bug?/Problem: If i click on authenticate and log in, everything works fine. If i log out, i log out. BUT if i dont close the pop-up (just try to relogin, it sends the same authentication code in the header. I get the following Error:
auth errorError: Bad Request, error: invalid_grant, description: Code not valid

But if i close the pop-up and reopen it and try to login, it works fine. And the code sent with the header is different.

So is it a Bug or do i have to change something in my Code?

I was expecting that it should send a new code in the header.